# editing the xml using ant task

Tags: ant

I was trying to edit the my config.xml file using ant task but I could not do that can anybody tell me How can I edit the xml using ant task automatically so that i dont need to change it manually for every new branch?

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question?  Will make it possible to give a less generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first option to check would be the Ant [`xslt`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) task.  For an introduction to its use see the [Ant/XSLT Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Apache_Ant/XSLT).

Answer (score 1):

I've used groovy to do this. groovy is very Java like, so you can create your groovy classes very similarly to a static java method, and have ant call out to your groovy script using the `<groovy>` task (you will of course need to include the groovy task def).

Because groovy can use Java syntax you can include the org.w3c.com.* libraries to have access to DOM classes.

For example, snippet of code showing the adding a resource ref element to a specifed web.xml file :-

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;

String web_xml_filename=args[0];
String res_ref_name=args[1];
Document doc = DomHelper.getDoc(web_xml_filename);
Element rootNode=doc.getDocumentElement();
newNode = doc.createElement("resource-ref"); 
DomHelper.createElement(doc, newNode, "res-ref-name", res_ref_name);
DomHelper.createElement(doc, newNode, "res-type", "javax.sql.DataSource");
DomHelper.createElement(doc, newNode, "description", description);
DomHelper.createElement(doc, newNode, "res-auth", "Container");
rootNode.insertBefore(newNode, nodes.item(0));
DomHelper.writeDoc(doc, web_xml_filename, false);
```

To call from ant, use the groovy task :-

```
<groovy src="${e5ahr-groovy.dir}/addResoureRefToJBossWebXML.groovy" classpath="${groovy.dir}">
    <arg value="${jboss-web.xml}"/>
    <arg value="jdbc/somesource/>
    <arg value="java:jdbc/somesource"/>
</groovy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html). Pattern and Expression options won't let you use less than or more than, but it can be replaced with HTML entities. For example:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true">
    <!-- In config.xml this looks like <myVariable></myVariable> -->
    <regexp pattern="&lt;myVariable&gt;(.*)&lt;/myVariable&gt;" />
    <substitution expression="&lt;myVariable&gt;${myVariable.value}&lt;/myVariable&gt;" />
        <fileset dir="${user.dir}">
            <include name="config.xml" />
        </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```